# Cron job in Magento Module

Tags: magento, cron

I am trying to use Cron job in magento on my Linux (HostGator) server.
I have created a module in magento admin panel and I want to run it with mymodule but it is not working.
When I run it from cpanel, it is working properly and it takes time schedule from `'cpanel'`, but I want to run it according to time, which I have set in mymodule crontab.
Can any body advise me that it is necessary to set cronjob from `cpanel`? or it can be run from a module crontab at different time schedules?

Answer (score 1):

Please read this wiki article about the work of cron in Magento 
http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/1_-_installation_and_configuration/how_to_setup_a_cron_job

Answer (score 1):

First you need to configure Cron via Cpanel. Here is more info (with screenshots)    https://support.sweettoothrewards.com/entries/21196536-setting-up-cron-jobs-in-magento

Here is also my article that can give you more info how to setup cron in your custom magento extension and how cron works http://blog.belvg.com/magento-certified-developer-exam-setting-up-a-cron-job.html

Here is also very nice and free extension by Fabrizio Branca that will help you to test your cron jobs
http://www.fabrizio-branca.de/magento-cron-scheduler.html